# Getting the amount of rows in your dataset that aren't NULL for several columns?

Tags: mysql, null

My query:

```
SELECT name,address,phone,fax FROM clients WHERE state='TX';
```

What I'm trying to find out is how can I get the number of rows that have data in them for each column - as some fields may be NULL, but I'm interested to find out how many in the result set actually have data.

I do NOT want to restrict the result set I get back in any way other then I have already done above with the `WHERE` clause. What I want returned in addition to the result set for example is: the number of fields in the name field that have data (are not NULL) & the same thing for the address field etc

I do not need it for every column, just some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that :

```
sum(if(name    is null, 0, 1)) as have_names
```

is equivalent to (but slower) :

```
count(name) AS have_names
```

As for the original question, since a SELECT returns a tabular list of rows/colums your problem is where would the counts fit ? If you return them as extra lines, they will be in the wrong columns, and if you return them as extra columns, you'll get one for each line.

So you need to do two queries...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for but I think you want this:

```
select count(*)
from clients
where state = 'TX'
  and (
       name    is not null
    or address is not null
    or phone   is not null
    or fax     is not null
)
```

That will tell you how many rows in `clients` have a state of Texas and at least one of `name`, `address`, `phone`, and `fax` is not NULL.

**UPDATE**: Based on your question update I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select
    sum(if(name    is null, 0, 1)) as have_names,
    sum(if(address is null, 0, 1)) as have_address,
    sum(if(phone   is null, 0, 1)) as have_phone
    sum(if(fax     is null, 0, 1)) as have_fax
from clients
where state = 'TX'
```

You'll have to do two queries — one for the column values and one for the counts — as you're trying to get two distinct things.

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm looking for. I will update my post to try & make it more clear.

Comment: @Brett: Is that what you're looking for? If not then maybe include some sample input and output.